# Swift: Thread 1 signal SIGABRT in class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Tags: ios

I'm new to Swift. I'm using Xcode 7.3, and I'm making a photo filter app. When I click the "Apply Filter" button, the application crash, with following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputAngle.'

---

And highlights the code

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

in AppDelegate.swift with text "Swift: Thread 1 signal SIGABRT".
I have no idea what does this means.

Here is my completed code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var PhotoLibrary: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Camera: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageDisplay: UIImageView!

let context = CIContext(options: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func PhotoLibraryAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func CameraAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//seeing the image after you taken
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    ImageDisplay.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage;
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func applyFilter(sender: AnyObject) {

    //create image to filter
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: ImageDisplay.image!)

    //Add a color to a filter, 0.00-3.14?
    let selectedColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(1.24))]

    //Apply a filter to the image
    let filteredImage = inputImage?.imageByApplyingFilter("CIGammaAdjust", withInputParameters: selectedColor)

    let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage!, fromRect: (filteredImage?.extent)!)

    //pass the final image to the image view
    ImageDisplay.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)
}
}
```

Please reply me if you need more information.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: check your connection state of IBOutlets with storyboard or xib.

Comment: I checked, I didn't find any problem on connection..

Comment: sorry. I misunderstood that issue. I doubt that `inputImage?.imageByApplyingFilter("CIGammaAdjust", withInputParameters: selectedColor)`. does `CIGammaAdjust` filter use `kCIInputAngleKey`? According to check a manual for `CIGammaAdjust`, it doesn't use `kCIInputAngleKey` key.

Comment: OMG!! Yes! That's the problem is!! Thank you very very much!!!!!